# Data.Map type declaration

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Map as Map

test :: Int -> Int -> Map -> Map
test key value cache = Map.insert key value cache
```

Error:

```
`Map' is not applied to enough type arguments
Expected kind `??', but `Map' has kind `* -> * -> *'
In the type signature for `test': test :: Int -> Int -> Map -> Map
```

How can I declare the function to pass Data.Map as parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to say what it is a map *of*.

```
test :: Int -> Int -> Map Int Int -> Map Int Int
test key value cache = Map.insert key value cache
```

Your keys are `Int`s and the values you're storing are also `Int`s, so your map has type `Map Int Int`.

If the keys were `String`s and the values were `Bool`s, the map would have type `Map String Bool`.